# what is the meaning of this? setTimeOut(() => this.active=true, 0)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am practicing angularjs2 and I notice this sentence but cannot understand what this means.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hero-form',
    templateUrl: 'app/hero-form.component.html'
})

export class HeroFormComponent {

    model = new Hero(18, 'Dr IQ', this.powers[0], 'Chuck Overstreet');

    active = true;

    newHero() {
        this.model = new Hero(42, '', '');
        this.active = false;
        setTimeOut(()=> this.active=true, 0)*
    }

}
```

I know in JavaScript there is a function name `setTimeOut` but cannot understand the `()` and arrow `=>`...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the new JavaScript [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) notation. The line you quoted is almost equivalent to this piece of code in the traditional function notation:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.active = true;
}, 0);
```

However in the traditional notation, `this` will be bound to the global object (outside of strict mode - in strict mode, you will get a `ReferenceError`), due to how binding of this in execution contexts works. The traditional workaround before the introduction of arrow functions would be:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    self.active = true;
}, 0)
```

Arrow functions solve this problem by lexically binding `this`, just as any other variable, instead of defining their own. In addition to how `this` is treated, arrow functions do not implicitly define their own `arguments` or `super` variables either, but bind them lexically.

---

Digging deeper, what does `newHero()` do? It is a constructor function. When you call it, a new object is allocated, and it can be referred to within the function body by the variable `this`. The constructor sets two properties on the `this` object; these properties are `.model` and `.active`, being given specific values.

The expression `(() => this.active = true)` creates a function object. It describes what should execute at a later time. When the function object is *called*, the body gets executed. So the line of code creates the function object and gives it to `setTimeout()`, which will call the function object after the given length of time - in this case, 0 milliseconds.

Comment: Note that in your answer, `this` will be bound to the global object outside of strict mode, or yield a reference error in strict mode. Regular functions bind their own value for this, while arrow functions bind this lexically: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @JohannesH. Thanks, I didn't realize there were subtle semantic gotchas involving arrow functions and `this`. I am not well informed enough to fix my explanation; can you help me edit the answer to be more correct?

Comment: Note that arrow functions are just an abbreviated syntax for function expressions (and lexical *this*), lambda functions have always existed in javascript.

Comment: @Nayuki Edited your answer. Hope it helps you understanding the issue as well

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally i can understand :)